# I made a java application. The class is extended from javax.swing.JPanel

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

the paintComponent(Graphics) is overrided. But when I launch the program, it just displays the content of old another window which was at the place of my application's window.I tried minimizing, maximizing, clicking, typing and several such things but it remains the same

**Answer for the request of code**
Ok here is the code of the class. It is not main class, main class is different.
package display;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;//@Suppress Warnings 'unused' to Board
import Working.*;


public class Board extends JPanel implements Const{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int UDocks, CDocks, URun, CRun, UC, CC;
    public boolean isToss, isBat, isOdd;
    public ENGINE engine;
    public BufferedImage one, two, three, four, five, six, dock, Null;
    public int STATUS;

    public BufferedImage UHand, CHand;
    public String temp;
    public JFrame Final;public Dimension preferredsize=new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);

    public Board(){
        engine=new ENGINE(this);
        UDocks=CDocks=3;
        URun=CRun=UC=CC=0;

        this.STATUS=GAME_STARTED;
        this.addKeyListener(engine);this.setBackground(Color.green);

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graph)
    {
        super.paintComponent(graph);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "HI", "HU", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


        graph.setColor(Color.black);

        String a;
        if(STATUS==GAME_STARTED){
            graph.setColor(Color.green);
            graph.fillRect(0, 0, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);graph.setColor(Color.black);
            engine.StartGame();
            STATUS = Const.GAME_FIRST_INNINGS ;
            this.requestFocus();
            }
        if(STATUS!=GAME_ENDED){
            if(isToss&&isBat)a="User won the toss and decided to bat first";
            else if(isToss&&!isBat)a="User won the toss and decided to bowl first";
            else if(!isToss&&!isBat)a="CPU won the toss and decided to bat first";
            else a="CPU won the toss and decided to bowl first";

            graph.drawString(a, 112, 54);
            graph.drawString("User Number",  192, 153);
            graph.drawString("Computer Number", 675, 142);
            if(STATUS==GAME_FIRST_INNINGS)
                a="Innings No.1\t Batting"+(isBat?"User\n":"CPU\n")+"Score:"+(isBat?URun:CRun)+"\tDocks:"+(isBat?UDocks:CDocks);
            else a="Innings No.2\t Batting"+(isBat?"CPU\n":"User\n")+"Score:"+(isBat?CRun:URun)+"\tDocks"+(isBat?CDocks:UDocks)+"\nTarget:"+(isBat?URun+1:CRun+1);
            graph.drawString(a, 600, 46);
            graph.drawImage(UHand, 130, 180, 493, 608, this);
            graph.drawImage(CHand, 618, 180, 980, 606, this);this.requestFocus();
        }
        else
        {

            if(isOdd)temp="User selected ODD during toss";else temp="User selected EVEN during toss";
            if(isToss){
                temp.concat("\nUser won the toss and chosed to");
                temp.concat((isBat?"Bat first":"Bowl first"));
            }else{
                temp.concat("\nCPU won the toss and elected to");
                temp.concat((isBat?"Bowl first":"Bat first"));
                }
            if(isBat)
            {
                temp.concat("\nUser scored "+URun);
                temp.concat("\nCPU scored "+CRun);
            }else{temp.concat("\nCPU scored "+CRun);temp.concat("\nUser scored "+URun);}
            if(CRun>URun)temp.concat("\nCPU won");
            else temp.concat("\nUser won");
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, temp, "Match Summary", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);this.requestFocus();
        }






    }
    public boolean inttobool(int h)
    {
        if(!(h==0))return true;else return false;
    }
    public int booltoint(boolean h)
    {
        if(h)return 1;else return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return preferredsize;
    }
    public void addPaneltoFrame(Container cont)
    {
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cont.add("Center", this);

    }
}
```

Here is the code of Const interface

```
package display;

public interface Const {
    public final int GAME_STARTED=10;
    public final int GAME_TOSS_OVER=20;
    public final int GAME_FIRST_INNINGS=30;
    public final int GAME_SECOND_INNINGS=40;
    public final int GAME_ENDED=50;
    public final boolean TOSS_USER=true;
    public final boolean TOSS_CPU=false;
    public final boolean FIRST_USER=true;
    public final boolean FIRST_CPU=false;
    public final int BOARD_WIDTH=1150;
    public final int BOARD_HEIGHT=680;
    public final int HAND_WIDTH=360;
    public final int HAND_HEIGHT=425;
    public final boolean GAME_NEEDS_SAVING=true;
    public final boolean GAME_NEEDNOT_SAVE=false;
    public int booltoint(boolean h);
    public boolean inttobool(int h);
}
```

Here is the code of Main

```
package display;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
        JFrame Fram=new JFrame("Hand Cricket By S.GOVIND BALAJI");
        Fram.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Board h=new Board();
        h.repaint();
        h.addPaneltoFrame(Fram.getContentPane());
        Fram.pack();
        Fram.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Here is the code of Start

```
package display;

     import java.awt.event.*;
     import java.awt.*;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import Working.*;


    public class Start implements Const, ActionListener, KeyListener {
private JFrame Final;
private JPanel pan, jan;
private JLabel Text;
private JButton Odd, Even;
private ENGINE child;private boolean ISOdd, ISBat, Waiting=false, ISToss;
private int UNum, CNum;

public Start(ENGINE child)
{
    this.child=child;
    pan=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());jan=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    Text=new JLabel("It's time for the toss.\n\t\t\t Odd or Even?");
    Odd=new JButton("Odd");
    Even=new JButton("Even");
    Odd.addActionListener(this);
    Even.addActionListener(this);
    jan.add("West", Odd);
    jan.add("East", Even);
    pan.add("North", Text);
    pan.add("South", jan);
    Final=new JFrame("Welcome, Toss");
    Final.setContentPane(pan);
    Final.pack();

    Final.setBackground(Color.pink);
    Text.setForeground(Color.GREEN);Odd.setForeground(Color.GREEN);Odd.setForeground(Color.GREEN);  Final.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent src) {
    JButton main;
    main=(JButton)src.getSource();
    if(!Waiting){
    if(main==Odd)

        ISOdd=true;
    else 
        ISOdd=false;
    Waiting=true;
    Final.setVisible(false);
    Text.setText("Ok, Type the number for toss");
    Odd.setVisible(false);
    Even.setVisible(false);
    Final.setVisible(true);
    }else
    {
        ISBat=false;
        if(main==Odd)
            ISBat=true;

        this.child.child.isBat=ISBat;
        child.child.isToss=ISToss;
        child.child.isOdd=ISOdd;
        Final.setVisible(false);try{
            this.child.Toss_OVER=true;
        }catch(Throwable th){}
    }
}

@Override
public int booltoint(boolean h) {
    if(h)
    return 1;else return 0;

}
@Override
public boolean inttobool(int h) {
    if(h==1)return true;else return false;
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg) {
    if(!Waiting)
        return;
    UNum=Static.CharToInt(arg.getKeyChar());
    CNum=Static.Fluke(0, 6);
    ISToss=false;
    if(CNum+UNum%2==booltoint(ISOdd)){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You won the Toss\nComputer put"+CNum+"\nYou Put"+UNum+"\nYour Call"+(ISOdd?"Odd":"Even")
                +"\nActuall Result"+(ISOdd?"Odd":"Even")
                , "Toss Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        ISToss=true;
        Final.setVisible(false);
        Text.setText("Choose to bat or bowl");
        Odd.setText("Bat");
        Even.setText("Bowl");
        Odd.setVisible(true);
        Even.setVisible(true);
        Final.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost in the Toss\nComputer put"+CNum+"\nYou Put"+UNum+"\nYour Call"+(ISOdd?"Odd":"Even")
                +"\nActuall Result"+(ISOdd?"Even":"Odd")
                , "Toss Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        ISToss=false;
        ISBat=inttobool(Static.Fluke(0, 1));
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Computer decided to "+(ISBat?"bat":"bowl")+"first", "Choosed", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}
The images are in Right directories
Here is the code of Engine

```
package Working;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import display.*;

public class ENGINE implements KeyListener, Const {
    //DATA MEMBERS
    public  Board child;public Start Toss;
    public boolean Toss_OVER=false;
    //heloo


    public ENGINE(Board paremnt){
        this.child=paremnt;

    }
    public void StartGame(){
        Toss=new Start(this);
        while(!Toss_OVER){}
        return;


    }

/*INHERITED INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION*/
    @Override
    public int booltoint(boolean h) {
        if(h)
        return 1;else return 0;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean inttobool(int h) {
        if(h==1)return true;else return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent KE) {
        int Key=Static.CharToInt(KE.getKeyChar()), CKey;
        //User first batting& First Innings
        //*/*/*/*/*/*/*/***-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
        //-*---*--*--*-*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
        //@Minimize
        //-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
        if(child.isBat&&child.STATUS==GAME_FIRST_INNINGS){
        switch(Key)
        {
        case '0':if(child.UDocks==0){JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You have no docks remaining.Type Again", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);return;}
            child.UDocks--;
            child.UHand=child.dock;
            break;
        case '1':
            child.UHand=child.one;
            break;
        case '2':
            child.UHand=child.two;
            break;
        case '3':
            child.UHand=child.three;
            break;
        case '4':
            child.UHand=child.four;
            break;
        case '5':
            child.UHand=child.five;
            break;
        case '6':
            child.UHand=child.six;
            break;

        }CKey=Static.Fluke(0, 6);
        switch(CKey)
        {
        case '0':
            child.CHand=child.dock;
            break;
        case '1':
            child.CHand=child.one;
            break;
        case '2':
            child.CHand=child.two;
            break;
        case '3':
            child.CHand=child.three;
            break;
        case '4':
            child.CHand=child.four;
            break;
        case '5':
            child.CHand=child.five;
            break;
        case '6':
            child.CHand=child.six;
            break;

        }

        child.repaint();
        if((Key==CKey))
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You are out", "Wicket", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            child.STATUS=GAME_SECOND_INNINGS;
            child.repaint();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Key==0)
                child.UC=CKey;
            else
                child.UC=Key;
            child.URun+=child.UC;child.repaint();
        }       
        }
        //*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
        /*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*----*-*--*-*-**-*-*-*
         User First Batting&&&&&&Second INNINGS
         *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
         */
        else if(child.isBat&&child.STATUS==GAME_SECOND_INNINGS)
        {

                switch(Key)
                {
                case '0':
                    child.UHand=child.dock;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    child.UHand=child.one;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    child.UHand=child.two;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    child.UHand=child.three;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    child.UHand=child.four;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    child.UHand=child.five;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    child.UHand=child.six;
                    break;

                }
                if(child.CDocks!=0)
                CKey=Static.Fluke(0, 6);else CKey=Static.Fluke(1, 6);
                switch(CKey)
                {
                case '0':
                    child.CHand=child.dock;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    child.CHand=child.one;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    child.CHand=child.two;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    child.CHand=child.three;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    child.CHand=child.four;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    child.CHand=child.five;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    child.CHand=child.six;
                    break;

                }

                child.repaint();
                if((Key==CKey))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Computer is out", "Wicket", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    child.STATUS=GAME_ENDED;
                    child.repaint();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Key==0)
                        child.CC=Key;
                    else
                        child.CC=CKey;
                    child.CRun+=child.CC;child.repaint();
                    if(child.CRun>child.URun)child.STATUS=GAME_ENDED;
                }       

        }





        //*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
        /*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*----*-*--*-*-**-*-*-*
         User Second Batting&&&&&&Second INNINGS
         *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
         */



        else if(!child.isBat && child.STATUS==GAME_SECOND_INNINGS){
            switch(Key)
            {
            case '0':if(child.UDocks==0){JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You have no docks remaining.Type Again", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);return;}
                child.UDocks--;
                child.UHand=child.dock;
                break;
            case '1':
                child.UHand=child.one;
                break;
            case '2':
                child.UHand=child.two;
                break;
            case '3':
                child.UHand=child.three;
                break;
            case '4':
                child.UHand=child.four;
                break;
            case '5':
                child.UHand=child.five;
                break;
            case '6':
                child.UHand=child.six;
                break;

            }CKey=Static.Fluke(0, 6);
            switch(CKey)
            {
            case '0':
                child.CHand=child.dock;
                break;
            case '1':
                child.CHand=child.one;
                break;
            case '2':
                child.CHand=child.two;
                break;
            case '3':
                child.CHand=child.three;
                break;
            case '4':
                child.CHand=child.four;
                break;
            case '5':
                child.CHand=child.five;
                break;
            case '6':
                child.CHand=child.six;
                break;

            }

            child.repaint();
            if((Key==CKey))
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You are out", "Wicket", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                child.STATUS=GAME_ENDED;
                child.repaint();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if(Key==0)
                    child.UC=CKey;
                else
                    child.UC=Key;
                child.URun+=child.UC;child.repaint();
                if(child.URun>child.CRun)child.STATUS=GAME_ENDED;
            }       
            }
        //User second batting& First Innings
                //*/*/*/*/*/*/*/***-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
                //-*---*--*--*-*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
                //@Minimize
                //-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
        else if(!child.isBat&&child.STATUS==GAME_FIRST_INNINGS)
        {

                switch(Key)
                {
                case '0':
                    child.UHand=child.dock;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    child.UHand=child.one;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    child.UHand=child.two;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    child.UHand=child.three;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    child.UHand=child.four;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    child.UHand=child.five;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    child.UHand=child.six;
                    break;

                }
                if(child.CDocks!=0)
                CKey=Static.Fluke(0, 6);else CKey=Static.Fluke(1, 6);
                switch(CKey)
                {
                case '0':
                    child.CHand=child.dock;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    child.CHand=child.one;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    child.CHand=child.two;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    child.CHand=child.three;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    child.CHand=child.four;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    child.CHand=child.five;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    child.CHand=child.six;
                    break;

                }

                child.repaint();
                if((Key==CKey))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Computer is out", "Wicket", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    child.STATUS=GAME_SECOND_INNINGS;
                    child.repaint();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Key==0)
                        child.CC=Key;
                    else
                        child.CC=CKey;
                    child.CRun+=child.CC;child.repaint();
                }       

        }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of Static

```
package Working;

public class Static {
    public static double Fluke(double x, double y)
    {
        double h;
        h=Math.random() * (y-x);
        h+=x;
        return h;
    }
    public static int Fluke(int x, int y)
    {
        int h;
        h=(int)Math.random() * (y-x);
        h+=x;
        return h;
    }
    public static float Fluke(float x, float y)
    {
        float h;
        h=(float)Math.random() * (y-x);
        h+=x;
        return h;
    }
    public static int CharToInt(char x)
    {
        switch(x)
        {
        case '0':
            return 0;           
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':return 2;
        case '3':return 3;
        case '4':return 4;
        case '5':return 5;
        case '6':return 6;
        default:return 6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include the code you have written so far in the question. This will make it far more likely that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to call **repaint()** or **updateUI()** method after you operations.

Comment: I use repaint() int the ENGINE class.Try compiling my code.When launching, the repaint() is actually getting called automatically.But nothing was displaying it displays the part of previous contents of Eclipse Window.